# how to load image in array push concept using mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside the data push loop i am getting all the data from database including doctor ID. From the doctor ID how to get the image from the image folder location.

```
@foreach (DoctorView doctor in Model.DoctorViews)
            {
                @:myArray.push("@doctor.DoctorID","<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID + ".png"))" />", "@doctor.DoctorName", "@doctor.Email", "@doctor.CountryName", "@doctor.City", "@doctor.Mobile");

            }

        var data = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

            data.push({
                "id": myArray[i],
                //"name": "Draft",
                "doctorName": myArray[i + 1],
                "email": myArray[i + 2],
                "country": myArray[i + 3],
                "city": myArray[i + 4],
                "mobile": myArray[i + 5]

            })

            i = i + 5;
        }
```

Comment: "<img " + "src='" + "~/Doctor/" + doctor.DoctorID +".png"+ "'/>" is it correct?

Comment: do you want the image as blob

Comment: @Krishjs I want display the image in front end user view

Comment: @Krishjs i cannot able to get the image from the particular page

Comment: Add the Html part of your code in the question